Is there something missing in Jech's proof of Zermelo's Well-Ordering Theorem?
Here is the proof from p. 48 of the Millennium Edition, corrected 4th printing 2006:

My question: how do we know that there is any ordinal $\theta$ such that $A=\{a_\xi\,\colon\xi<\alpha\}$? Presumably we need to use the fact that $A$ is a set because if $A$ is a proper class I don't think it's true. On the other hand, I don't see how we've used it. Am I missing something? And if I'm not missing something, what is the easiest/most elegant way to patch the hole? If the process keeps going indefinitely, $A$ would have to be a proper class, but I am not clear on how to stick the landing on that approach.
Thank you!

See Jech's coverage of the Hartogs function in the proof of Lemma 3.4, bottom of p. 29.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number might be helpful

Thank you, @blargoner and @Lucenaposition! So it looks to me like there is something missing in the proof, and that this is the way to patch it.

@NatKuhn I'd hesitate to say it's missing, because that makes it sound like there's a problematic gap or hole. It's well within the realm of details Jech expects the reader to fill in using techniques he's illustrated. If that proof has a gap, then so does almost every other textbook proof.

If there is no such $\theta$, then there is a map from $A$ onto the class of ordinals, that's impossible, since $A$ is a set.

This was my intuition but I was not sure how to make it rigorous, but I see now that the axiom of replacement would imply that the class of all ordinals is a set.
